# Load all resources before loading Activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity which has to grab heavy images, resize them and loads into `GridView`. Since all this process of fetching, resizing is time consuming, when I try to load this screen from another `ACtivity`, I get a delay.

How can I first load the content of this "grid activity" and open it only after all images have been loaded?

Using `startActivityForResult`? If this is a solution, how can I detect that all images have been loaded since `GridView` load images on scroll.

**EDIT**

I was suggested to use `AsyncTask` which I used dozens of times before. But something confuses me.

1. Should I send custom adapter initialization to the AsyncTask?

   ```
   mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
   mGridView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
   ```
2. Or I should do async task inside of the custom adapter, namely inside the method `getView` and with each gridview cell create a new call to my `AsyncTask`?

Comment: understanding `AsyncTask` : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I would go with option 2. This way you can "bind" the `AsyncTask` to a cell and, whenever the cell is not shown, you can cancel the `AsyncTask` to prevent further processing. Just remember that only one `AsyncTask` is run at a time, since Android 3.1, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AsyncTask` by putting all the code of fetching and resizing in the `doInBacground` method, you can save data in an object (may be an `ArrayList` of `Bitmap`) to be returned to the `onPostExecute` method (see [AsyncTask genric types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)).

Then will also have to change your `ImageAdapter` constructor by adding the object you got from `AsyncTask` to it as a parameter.

```
public class DownloadPdfTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Bitmap>> {
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> images;
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /** your long task here, and set "images" **/
        return images;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(images);
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, images); // new construcor
        mGridView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    }
```

}

Use the `images` list as you want in your Adapter !

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an `AsyncTask`.

Create your `Activity` normally. At the end of `onCreate()`, start your `AsyncTask`.

On your `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute()` method, make some animation or message appear to the user.

On `doInBackground()` work on your images.

On `onPostExecute()`, load your images on the `GridView` and stop the animation or dismiss the message.

This way, your `Activity` won't have the delay you mentioned while being created.